# Can not reload the page when navigating to the other page Using Angular.js and UI-Router

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have one issue regarding the page reload using Angular.js.I am using the Angular.js `UI-Router` for navigating the pages.Let me to explain my code first.

> router.js:

```
var Admin=angular.module('Channabasavashwara',['ui.router', '720kb.datepicker','ngMessages','ngCapsLock','ui.bootstrap']);
Admin.run(function($rootScope, $state) {
      $rootScope.$state = $state;
    });
Admin.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');
    $stateProvider
     .state('/', { /*....This state defines All type of user login...*/
            url: '/',
            templateUrl: 'dashboardview/login.html',
            controller: 'loginController'
        })

        /*.........START OF ROOT ADMIN STATES.........*/
        .state('dashboard', { /* This state defines The root admin login page. */
            url: '/dashboard',
            templateUrl: 'dashboardview/dashboard.html',
            controller: 'adminController'
        })
        .state('dashboard.profile', {  /* This states defines College profile page */
        url: '/profile',
        templateUrl: 'dashboardview/profile.html',
        controller: 'adminCollegeProfileController'
    })
    .state('dashboard.res', {  /* This state defines  the home page of Resource management ...*/
        url: '/res',
        templateUrl: 'dashboardview/res.html',
        controller: 'adminResController'
    })
});
```

Here `dashboard.html` is my home page.Suppose i made some changes in `profile.html and res.html` and  i reloaded the page staying in home page.When i visited other two pages the changes are not visible.It is visible after refreshing each individual page.Here I need once user will refresh the any page all changes should reflect in respective pages.Please help me.

Comment: maybe a cache issue ?

Comment: @NitsanBaleli : How it can be resolved inside the code.

Comment: refresh the page with Ctrl + F5  key

Comment: @RishiSaraf : I know that.Please read my post.

Comment: what i mean to say ctrl+f5 will do force refresh and all the files will be fetched from server instead of browser cache. You can clear browser cache manually (ctrl + shift + delete) and select option files-images. Else you fix the cache issue by renaming your files, it can be automatically done as part of build. Check https://github.com/cbas/grunt-rev